Rounding Margins in Android Studio
I am trying to round the corners of the Margins on an xml file. Is this possible? I have looked around a little bit and can't seem to find a solution to my problem.
I have tried adding things to drawables to affect my margins but nothing seemed to work

please add more details on what you are trying to achieve. There's no concept like "margins of an XML file". Maybe you are trying to edit a shape / drawable. Tell us more so that we can help you

I'm not sure what you are trying to say about Rounded Margins but I always used CardView to have a rounded corners and then put the elements inside it. For that, a drawable resource is not needed.
